# Как установить на компьютер платформу для обучения JAVA

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, что необходимо для изучения языка программирования JAVA в домашних условиях. Где и какую платформу можно установить (Windows 10 домашняя).

Comment: Вы `Java` установили? (не помню, идет ли по умолчанию в винде или нет, если нет, скачате с сайта `oracle.com`) Скачайте `IDE Netbeans` например и вперед и с песней.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установка JDK (Java Development Kit) с сайта Oracle и среды выполнения Java (IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse или NetBeans);

Вот [тут](https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-552745090cd6) хорошая статья на тему "с чего начать".

Answer (score 0):

Для начала Вам понадобится **JDK** и какая-нибудь среда разработки, например **Intellij Idea** или **NetBeans**. Скачать JDK можно [тут](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) , NetBeans [тут](https://netbeans.org/downloads/), Intellij Idea [тут](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/idea/download/) для начала вполне хватит Community версии.

Затем уже можно приступить к изучению :)

Могу посоветовать книгу **Изучаем Java**(Берт Бейтс и Кати Сьерра), а так же базовый курс от **JavaBegin**. Скачать можно [тут](http://javabegin.ru/dl/)

Удачи :)